# Fade a background in when you mouseover a box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, mouseover, fade

I've asked this guestion before. But now I'll try to be a bit more specific.

I've trying to make a background fade in when you mouse over a box. I've tried 2 different options.

Option 1: 
Box1 is the box it mousesover, and hover1 is the new background that comes in. This actually works pretty well. However, it loads the acript, meaning, that if i just go crazy with my mouse over the box, the fadeing will continue endless, even when my mouse is standing still. Is there a way you can stop it?
Content is a text that changes in a contentbox when I mouseover. This worksfine.

```
$("#box1").mouseover(function(){
    $("#background").switchClass("nohover", "hover1", 500);
    $("#content").html(box1);

});

$("#box1").mouseout(function(){
    $("#background").switchClass("hover1", "nohover", 150);
    $("#content").html(content);

});
```

Option 2:
Here i add the class hover2 and asks it to fadeín and fadeout. But this doesn't work at all. Somtimes it even removes everything on the side when i take the mouseout of the box.

```
$("#box2").mouseover(function(){
    $("#background").addClass("hover2").fadeIn("slow") 
    $("#content").html(box3);
});

$("#box2").mouseout(function(){
    $("#background").removeClass("hover2").fadeOut("slow")
    $("#content").html(content);
});
```

I Use jquery ui.
I really hope someone can help me!

Comment: Is `switchclass` a plugin? It sounds like you need to add `stop()` before calling `animate()` assuming you can amend the source.

Comment: Yes, SWichClass is a plugin from jquery ui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try to make small changes in the markup/CSS.

*HTML:*

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="background"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
#box {
    position: relative;
    /* ... */
}
#background {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    background-image: url(...);
    z-index: -1;
}​
```

*JavaScript:*

```
$("#box").hover(function() {
    $("#background").fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $("#background").stop().fadeOut();
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/bRfMy/

Comment: Animating opacity works way better than fadeIn/fadeOut: http://jsfiddle.net/bRfMy/1/

Comment: @Codemonkey How come if they do the same things?

Comment: They don't. fadeIn and fadeOut also controls the display property. Just try moving the mouse in and out fast using your solution, then try mine

Answer (score 0):

Try add a variable to control the execution of the effect only when that variable has a certain value. And modify its value when the effect was executwed.

Something like this:

```
var goeft = 0;
$("#box1").mouseover(function(){
  if(goeft == 0) {
    $("#background").switchClass("nohover", "hover1", 500);
    $("#content").html(box1);
    goeft = 1;
  }
});

$("#box1").mouseout(function(){
    $("#background").switchClass("hover1", "nohover", 150);
    $("#content").html(content);
    // sets its value back to 0 if you want the next mouseover execute the effect again
    goeft = 0;
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer..
But, this still doesn't stop the animation running if I mouseover the but very fast multiple times.