# Jquery - background fade.

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, mouseover, fade

I'm trying to make a background fade in when you mouse over a box.

Box1 is the box I mousesover, and hover1 is the new background that comes in. This actually works pretty well. However, it loads the acript, meaning, that if i go crazy with my mouse over the box, the fadeing will continue endless, even when my mouse is standing still. I need to add some kind of stop function..
Content is a text that changes in a contentbox when I mouseover. This works fine.

```
$("#box1").mouseover(function(){
    $("#background").switchClass("nohover", "hover1", 500);
    $("#content").html(box1);

});

$("#box1").mouseout(function(){
    $("#background").switchClass("hover1", "nohover", 150);
    $("#content").html(content);

});
```

I've also tried with var, but I still have the same problem. If I mouseover fast, the fading keeps running.

```
    var goeft = 0;
$("#box1").mouseover(function(){
 if(goeft == 0) {
   $("#background").switchClass("nohover", "hover1", 500);
  $("#content").html(box1);
   goeft = 1;
 }
});

$("#box1").mouseout(function(){
    $("#background").switchClass("hover1", "nohover", 150);
   $("#content").html(content);

   goeft = 0;
});
```

Css code -v-

```
      /* CSS Document */
       body
      {
      background-color:#B1EB78;
      }

     #wrapper
     {
     border:5px white solid;
     border-radius:15px;
     background-image:url(../images/mill.jpg);
     }

     #header
     {
     height:120px;
     background-image:url(../images/logo.png);
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     }

     #content
     {
     height:250px;
     background-image:url(../images/trans_white.png);
     border:1px black solid;
     border-radius:5px;
     }

     #space
     {
     height:40px;
     }

     #space2
     {
     height: 10px;
     }

     #box1
     {
     height:250px;
     background-image:url(../images/trans_green.png);
     }




     #background
     {
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     border-radius:9px;
     }


    .hover1
    {
    background-color:red;

    }

   .nohover
   {

   }
```

Comment: You've already [asked the similar thing and got couple of solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533130/fade-a-background-in-when-you-mouseover-a-box/).

Comment: Dear question asker; Could you please recreate your issue in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? It allows people to observe and play with your code, making it much easier to find a solution. Additionally, often when I'm about to ask a question on SO, I first recreate my issue in JSFiddle and then promptly spot and fix the problem myself.

Comment: I can't put it in JSFiddle, cause a lot of my files are local. I fx. don't link to an online jquery.. So it would'nt work in jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var goeft = 0;
$("#box1").mouseenter(function(){
 if(goeft == 0) {
   $("#background").switchClass("nohover", "hover1", 500);
  $("#content").html(box1);
   goeft = 1;
 }
});

$("#box1").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#background").switchClass("hover1", "nohover", 150);
   $("#content").html(content);

   goeft = 0;
});
```

I have no idea about the classes but i think mouseenter and mouseleave are better alternative for mouseout and mouseover

Comment: I've put my entire css file up in my original post.

Comment: Sad news : There is some problem with switchclass, when you mouseout the cursor before the mouseover animation completes then the mouseout function don't run as its class is not changed to hover1 from nohover at that time.

Comment: If you want then i can give you an alternative

Comment: You just post your html code and i will give you desired solution

Comment: Make a div(background-color:#ff0000;) and set its z-index -1 and #background div z-index 2 ,then place new div and #background on same location ,after that onmouseover and mouseout animate the opacity property of new div.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it out tomorrow, unfortunately I don't have any more time today.